# How can I pull out useful metrics from SonarQube

Tags: python, sonarqube

I am trying to pull out useful metrics from SonarQube (like lines of code, technical debt, sqale rating, etc).

The issue is I am stuck on the best way to do this.  I am looking at their Web Service API documentation, http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392172.  Is this same thing as a RESTful service?

So as a simple example...Nemo is a public demo of SonarQube.
And the following demonstrates how to get lines of code.

Get the metric 'Lines of Code' (key = ncloc)
GET http://nemo.sonarsource.org/api/metrics/ncloc

So my question is, can I write a Python program or something to grab the metrics I want from SonarQube? Is this a RESTful API? What is the best way to get this data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I know its a 4 year old post but I was working on it now and this works for lines of code -

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
token = 'xxx'
PARAM = {'component': 'your_project', 'metricKeys': 'ncloc'}
test_url = 'http://sonarqube.com:9000/api/measures/component'
test_response = requests.get(test_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username=token, password=""), verify=False,params=PARAM)
test_json = test_response.json()
print(test_json)
```

Comment: Thanks Manu, you've saved my life today!!! I have no exp with sonar and was to fetch a similar thing, this post and this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526635/sonarqube-rest-apis-read-metrics-for-individual-projects, have been extremely helpful in my info fetching process! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to interact with SonarQube from an external point of view is indeed to use this Web Service API.

You can find every available web service:

- either on the [Web Service API page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE43/Web+Service+API) documented on the Wiki, for old versions of SonarQube
- or better directly inside SonarQube itself in recent versions, like [what you can see on Nemo](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation)

Comment: Could you please suggest which APIs we have to use for new version of Sonarqube?