# SonarQube REST APIs : Read Metrics for individual projects

Tags: sonarqube

**My question:**

I am using SonarQube version 7.1 and trying to extract the metrics and quality gate related to individual projects.

**What we have tried**

We were using Python SonarQube API to extract these data before our company upgraded to version 7.1. "api/resources" web service Deprecated since sonarqube5.4, so we cannot use it anymore.

I have also tried using getting data using CURL command via Web API using
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "x-api-key:token" -X GET 'http://MY_HOST/api/measures/component?metricKeys=key&component=project_key'
 We are able to get a json payload for individual metrics, but involves tedious task of creating the URL every single time.

But I wanted to know if there is a better/smarter way to access these "measures", be it any language or implementation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could do this:

Call the API `api/metrics/search` first to get a (json) list of all the metrics and then iterate over that list and create a comma separated string of all the metric keys.

For example something like this: `ncloc,complexity,violations` .. as mentioned in the parameters example value in the API documentation [here](https://SONAR_HOST/web_api/api/measures).

Then you could just add this comma separated list to the url as a parameter  something like: `http://MY_HOST/api/measures/component?metricKeys=ncloc,complexity,violations&component=project_key`

and call it once to get the response for all metrics.

Also, I haven't tried this, but as per the latest documentation, the parameter `component` is optional. So if you omit that, ideally you should get a response with metrics of all the projects.

Comment: In my version of SonarQube (6.3), that last parameter (component) should be named componentKey

Comment: Done, works awesome! Does anyone know how to get a detailed metric info? All i get is this for all metrics
{
        "metric": "code_smells",
        "bestValue": false,
        "value": "48"
      }

Comment: Here you can get detailed metric info: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/metric-definitions/

Comment: is there a way to get measures values user wise?